# Past simple or Past perfect prgressive

Tags: grammar, past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple, past-continuous

which one is the correct sentence between the two and why?

Before I lost my job, I **was** working on some important projects.

or

Before I lost my job, I **had been** working on some important projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. was working

Past progressive means actions performed or occurred at a certain moment or a certain period of time in the past. Its form is was /were + V-ing. It is often used with adverbials of time in the past, such as: last night, last Saturday, etc.; or used with adverbials of past time guided by when, while, and as.

example : We were watching TV from seven to nine last night.

2. had been working

The Past Perfect Progressive
Represents actions that have been performed before a certain time in the past.
example: I had been looking for it for days before I found it.

you shuold use the past perfect progressive

Answer (score 0):

Both are possible:

If you were working on a project it means that during a period of time, before you lost your job, you were doing the project, which was a temporary thing.

If you had been working on the project it emphasizes a longer period of time, even though the duration is not mentioned. It could also mean the work on the project had stopped before the job was lost.